# GitHub Action: zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r ./bundle.zip . -i ./.)

Tags: github, zip, github-actions

I have a project dir like so:

```
└── lambda
    └── lambda_handler.py
```

With the following .yml file

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: zip
        uses: montudor/action-zip@v0.1.0
        with:
          args: "zip -r ./bundle.zip ./."
      - name: default deploy
        uses: appleboy/lambda-action@master
        with:
          aws_access_key_id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws_region: eu-west-3
          function_name: generate_crawler_threads_from_processes    
          zip_file: bundle.zip
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qq -r bundle.zip . -i lambda/)
```

No matter how I tried to perform the zipping step, it didn't work.

Here's a list of other variations of `zip` command usage I have tried:

```
zip -r bundle.zip ./*
zip -r ./bundle.zip ./*
zip -r bundle.zip .
zip -r ./bundle.zip .
zip -r bundle.zip /
zip -r bundle.zip ./
zip -r ./bundle.zip .
zip -r bundle.zip *
zip -qq -r bundle.zip .
zip -qq -r bundle.zip . -i .
zip -qq -r bundle.zip . -i lambda/
```

And many more. Simply it will keep throwing the same error.

Comment: Note that [tag:git] is irrelevant here. GitHub actions are specific to GitHub (although something extremely similar appears on other hosting providers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [montudor/action-zip usage section](https://github.com/montudor/action-zip#usage), it seems you need to add the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) to access the repository files and directory before using it.

Something like this:

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: zip
        uses: montudor/action-zip@v0.1.0
        with:
          args: "zip -r ./bundle.zip ./."
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: bundle.zip
```